# Using future.onComplete with Java and Akka and a different Result as String

Tags: java, akka, future

I have the following question...

I'm using Akka 2.3.6 from Java and would like to get the following done:

```
Future<Object> future = ask(actor, new GetPOIDataMessage(tenant), Timeout.durationToTimeout(duration));
    future.onSuccess(new OnComplete<NonSimpleObject>() {
                          public void onComplete(Throwable failure, final NonSimpleObject data) {
                              if (failure != null) {
                                  deferredResult.setErrorResult("An error occured during the request");
                              } else {
                                  deferredResult.setResult(data);
                              }
                          }
                      }, ec);
```

NonSimpleObject is the type of the message sent back from the actor. I get the following error compiling my code:

```
error: method onSuccess in interface Future<T> cannot be applied to given types;
[error]         future.onSuccess(new OnComplete<NonSimpleObject>() {    
[error]               ^
[error]   required: PartialFunction<Object,U>,ExecutionContext
[error]   found: <anonymous OnComplete< NonSimpleObject >>,ExecutionContext
[error]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) U
[error]     (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnComplete< NonSimpleObject >> cannot be converted to PartialFunction<Object,U>)
[error]   where U,T are type-variables:
[error]     U extends Object declared in method <U>onSuccess(PartialFunction<T,U>,ExecutionContext)
[error]     T extends Object declared in interface Future`
```

which I fail to decode. Seems to be over my head right now.
It works fine with a String as the result. I could not find other examples on the web that are using something different as a String.

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction. Jan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem stems from trying to use an `OnComplete<NonSimpleObject>` as opposed to an `OnComplete<Object>`.  The `Future` you have is `Future<Object>`, so it stands to reason that you can only use an `OnComplete<Object>`.  I don't think you can cast either as that didn't seem to work for me.  Here is a simplified working example of what you were trying to do:

```
public class NonSimpleObject{
  public final int i;
  public final String s;

  public NonSimpleObject(String s, int i){
      this.s = s;
      this.i = i;
  }
}

public class SimpleActor extends UntypedActor{
  public SimpleActor(){

  }
  public void onReceive(Object msg){
    getSender().tell(new NonSimpleObject("foo", 11), getContext().self());
  }
}

import scala.concurrent.Future;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import static akka.pattern.Patterns.ask;
import akka.dispatch.*;

class AskTest{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
    ActorRef ref = system.actorOf(Props.create(SimpleActor.class));
    Future<Object> fut = ask(ref, "foo", 1000);
    fut.onComplete(new OnComplete<Object>(){
        public void onComplete(Throwable t, Object result){
          System.out.println(((NonSimpleObject)result).s);
        }
    }, system.dispatcher());
  }
}
```

The interoperability between Java and Scala with Futures does not seem to be all that great.  This example is much easier in pure scala and seems quite a bit clunky in Java.  In Scala, `Future` has `mapTo` so you can get the correct type for your `Future` but I didn't see any analog that can be used in Java.

**EDIT**

After playing around a bit, I found a pretty hackish way to use `mapTo` on the `Future` to get proper typing.  You could try something like this, but like I said, it's hackish in how it gets the required Scala `ClassTag` for `mapTo`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import scala.reflect.ClassTag$;
import scala.reflect.ClassTag;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import static akka.pattern.Patterns.ask;
import akka.dispatch.*;

class AskTest{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
    ActorRef ref = system.actorOf(Props.create(SimpleActor.class));

    ClassTag<NonSimpleObject> tag = ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(NonSimpleObject.class);
    Future<NonSimpleObject> fut = ask(ref, "foo", 1000).mapTo(tag);
    fut.onComplete(new OnComplete<NonSimpleObject>(){
        public void onComplete(Throwable t, NonSimpleObject result){
          System.out.println(result.s);
        }
    }, system.dispatcher());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the work you put into this. You are correct with your assumption that I forgot about the correct types in the first place. I tried some stuff in the meantime and while I was not successful to cast in onComplete() from Object to the correct class (try it with the test on the Throwable as in the Akka docs for Java-Futures - won't compile here...), it was working on onSuccess(). So I used onSuccess() and onFailure() on the Future instead of onComplete().